# Laravel selectRaw summed column not found

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a custom table widget in filament for showing best selling products. When I do `sum(quantity) as total_quantity`, it gives me `Column not found` error. Here's my entire code and the error message :

```
    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->query(
                OrderDetails::query()
                    ->selectRaw('product_id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity')
                    ->groupBy('product_id')
                    ->orderBy('total_quantity', 'desc')
            )
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('product.name'),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('total_quantity'),
            ]);
    }
```

Error message with the compiled SQL :

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'total_quantity' in 'order clause'

select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  `order_details`
group by
  `product_id`
order by
  total_quantity,
  `order_details`.`id` asc
```

The weird thing is, as you can see, the compiled SQL code doesn't have `sum(quantity) as total_quantity` in it.

Comment: `orderBy` it's being applied to the initial query, at that point, the `total_quantity` generated column, doesn't exist in order to sort the results.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in a comment, `total_quatity` column isn't available to sort the query, you'll need to perform a subquery to achieve your desired result.

You can try this instead:

```
public function table(Table $table): Table
{
    $subQuery = OrderDetails::query()
        ->selectRaw('product_id, sum(quantity) as total_quantity')
        ->groupBy('product_id')
        ->orderByRaw('sum(quantity) desc');

    return $table
        ->query(
            DB::query()->fromSub($subQuery, 'sub')
        )
        ->columns([
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('product.name'),
            Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('total_quantity'),
        ]);
}
```

Comment: It was one of the suggestions ChatGPT gave. However it still doesn't work. It says it has to be a closure, it makes me furious that you can't just give an array to loop through and turn it into a table widget. The code works perfectly anywhere else in the project.

"Filament\Tables\Table::query(): Argument #1 ($query) must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|Closure|null, Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder given, called in /home/user/Laravel Projects/projectName/app/Filament/Widgets/BestSellingProducts.php on line 22"

Comment: what if you add `toBase()` to the query? have you tried it?

Comment: It didn't change anything. "must be of type ...\Eloquent\Builder|Closure, Database\Query\Builder given" And there's not a single information about table widgets in filament docs either...